# move image on tilt within boundaries

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I'm currently creating a iPhone app that displays my speed heading location and a few other sensor readings for use on my bike. I've managed to get the tilt reading from the accelerator. what I'm trying to do is move an image either left or right depending on what the tilt reading is.

```
    _______________________________
    :          ===                :
    :          = =                :
    :          ===                :
    -------------------------------
```

lets say the = signs is my image, I'm trying to get it to move either towards the left or right edge depending on the tilt angle.

any ideas? I've managed to move it by animations but I don't want it to continuously move if I'm leaning for a long period of time.

Comment: So you have the accelerator data and are just trying to figure out how to get a smooth animation for the tilt?  Or are you trying to figure out accelerator data also?

Comment: thats right, i know how to animate, and i have the tilt angle. im trying to get the UIImageView to move to the left or right depending howfar the device is tilted. im guesing i have to divide the movement boundaries into a percentage and then depending on how far its tilted depends on what percent it moves?

Comment: That is what I would do.  Just update the center of the image with animation every time the tilt changes significantly.  I'll write an answer when I get home if you don't have anything figured out by then.

Comment: thanks that would be most appreciated, iv got the idea in my head but trying to put that down on paper is making my eyes bleed.

Comment: Sorry it took me a minute, I got tied up last night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I added the accelerator data using:

```
UIAccelerometer *theAccelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
theAccelerometer.updateInterval = 0.1; //in seconds
theAccelerometer.delegate = self;
```

Notice the timing is 0.1 seconds.  You will want to match that timing to the animation below.  I then set the animation up in the `accelerometer:didAccelerate:` delegate call:

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration

{
    NSInteger newX = 0;

    newX = imageView.frame.size.width/2 + ((320-imageView.frame.size.width) * (acceleration.x+1)/2.0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        imageView.center = CGPointMake(newX, imageView.center.y);
    }] ;
}
```

It is important to match the animation duration with the `updateInterval` of the `UIAccelerometer` so that you make sure to complete the animation before the next update comes through.

The important part here is probably the math to determine the `newX` position.  I basically took half of the width of the image, because that is the left most absolute position.  From there I knew I had a `320-imageView.frame.size.width` amount of room that I could add.  If I added the entire `320-imageView.frame.size.width` then I would be at `320-imageView.frame.size.width/2` which is the right-most position.  From there I just needed to break up the `320-imageView.frame.size.width` chunk according to how much we have accelerated.  The `accelerator.x` data is in the range -1 to 1, so my entire range is 2.  So I added 1 to the `accelerator.x` to normalize it from 0-2.  Then I divided by 2.0 so that I would have a range from 0-1.  Now I had a multiplier that I could multiply my `320-imageView.frame.size.width` range by.  If it was 0 I would be at the left-most position.  If it was 1 I would be at the right-most position, and anything in between would be broken up linearly.  So the final term is:

```
imageView.frame.size.width/2 + ((320-imageView.frame.size.width) * (acceleration.x+1)/2.0);
```

to get the new x position of the image.

I hope that is what you are looking for!  I tested it on a device and it is pretty smooth as long as you match up your durations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code worked perfectly. i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking the question about animation. This is code apple recommnad to animate UIView. And you can change value for x and y coordinate.

```
    imageFrame.origin.y = 200;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     datePickerView.frame = imageFrame;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     self.datePickerViewFlag = YES;
                 }];
```